# UIButton constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created "first button" using storyboard and set its constraints for it, now I want to create another button programmatically and set it above the first button like this : [image: image of buttons]

and I use this code to try and achieve this:

```
  NSLayoutConstraint *xConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0];


    NSLayoutConstraint *Yxonstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.invoiceTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:200];

    NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:200];

    [self.view addConstraints:@[xConstraint,Yxonstraints,width,height]];
```

However the second button ends up in the middle and on the left and also smaller than its actual size, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
self.secondBu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
    self.secondBu.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.firstBu.topAnchor, constant:-15)  
    self.secondBu.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.firstBu.leadingAnchor), 
    self.secondBu.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.firstBu.trailingAnchor),
    self.secondBu.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.firstBu.heightAnchor)
])
```

but the easiest way is to insert firstBu inside `UIStackView` in storyboard , and then use 1 line

```
self.stackView.insertArrangedSubview(secondBu,at:0)
```

you may set stackView spacing property to 15 also in IB , also avoid using `addConstraints` as recommended by Apple and use `NSLayoutConstraint.activate`

Comment: [button.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.checkoutBtn.topAnchor constant:-15]; is this the equivalent for objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSLayoutConstraint *Yxonstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.invoiceTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
```

You don't want that. You want secondButton.top be space to firstButton.bottom :

```
 NSLayoutConstraint *Yxonstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.invoiceTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:20];
```